# Put cropped part of image back in original dimensions

Tags: matlab

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I've got a problem since two days with a larger image and a ROI, which is part of the image.
I want to use `imrect` for selecting the ROI and cropping the ROI out, so that I have a smaller amount of data to process.
After processing I want to re-map the cropped image back to the original position of the image.

What I've done so far by debugging:

```
function paddedImg = putCroppedImgBack(croppedIm, Pos, origDim)
paddedImg = zeros(origDim);
r = round(Pos(1));
c = round(Pos(2));
if(r ==0) % because ML addresses a matrix not with 0 like in cpp
     r=1;
end
sizeR = size(croppedIm,1);
sizeC = size(croppedIm,2);
paddedImg(r:sizeR,c:sizeC) = croppedIm; %this part doesn't work!
%Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

I tried to `round` the coordinates of the `imrect`, but that didn't worked aswell.
I also adressed manually `paddedImg` with the values, e.g. 
`paddedImg(1:5,20:50) = 1;`, which works.

**edit:**
Found the solution after I started the post here....  sometimes I should ask StackOverflow a little bit earlier than spending a whole day with a sleepless night.

`paddedImg(r:sizeR+r-1,c:sizeC+c-1) = croppedIm;`

Sincerely

Comment: Try passing `Pos = [1 1]` and tell us if it gives the same error. Or try `paddedImg(1:5,20:50) = croppedImg` to see if it works.

Comment: Oh sweet lord, I think that I've found the mistake...
Sometimes life is so ironic. As I read your post I tried something, which I'd thought I already tried before.
See the edit in the start post. Anyways.. thanks for your post.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful, in some ways. Post your solution as an answer, you'll be able to accept it in two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: Found the solution after I started the post here.... sometimes I should ask StackOverflow a little bit earlier than spending a whole day with a sleepless night.

`paddedImg(r:sizeR+r-1,c:sizeC+c-1) = croppedIm;`